# Why deleting a pointer to a vector of pointers causes the pointers to be not valid?

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

**EDIT**: thank you for the answers! I declared the `tellSomething` method with a `std::string` return type while it should have been `void`!

I was tripping myself up and blamed the poor guiltless `delete` operator :)!

---

Let's consider a pointer to a dynamically allocated `vector` which contains pointers to dynamically allocated objects:

```
// Create the vector of pointers
std::vector<A *>* v = new std::vector<A *>;

// Create two objects
A *a1 = new A;
A *a2 = new A;

// Populate the vector
v->push_back(a1);
v->push_back(a2);

// Delete the vector
delete v;

// Try accessing one of the objects
a1->tellSomething();    --> // Segmentation fault
```

As expected, if I delete the `vector`, the `delete` on the contained objects is not called (I also verified that `A::~A()` is never called in the above code), however, the last instruction gives a segmentation fault.

What I expect from the `delete v` is two things:

- The destructor for every contained object is called
- The container is deallocated

But in this case the contained objects are pointers, so no destructor is called.

Also, `a1` is not `NULL` at the end of the listing.

So, why the segmentation fault?

---

Complete example here: http://ideone.com/r8YC0.

---

Note: I don't usually use raw pointers with STL containers, please, consider this code as a purely theoretic example to help me understanding the logic of the `delete v` instruction.

Comment: is it something `a1->tellSomething` is doing?

Comment: I believe that the `delete` keyword calls the vector's destructor, which in-turn deletes all of your pointers

Comment: That should not happen. How do you know it is not inside the tellSomething() method - have you excluded this possibility?

Comment: @SamIam, Vectors don't free pointers when destructed AFAIR. You have to  free them manually, which is why smart pointers work well there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The crash you get is completely unrelated; you declared `tellSomething` as returning a `std::string`, but you never return anything, so you go into undefined behavior-land; the fact that the program crashed after deallocating the vector is sheer luck, it could have crashed even at the first call to `tellSomething`.

[Fixing that problem](http://ideone.com/Vrtgd) makes your program run fine (although you are leaking `a1` and `a2`).

By the way, this teaches you to turn up all the warnings: with `-Wall` that code would have given you an explicit warning about this potential problem:

```
matteo@teolapmint ~/cpp $ g++ -Wall testwarns.cpp 
testwarns.cpp: In member function ‘std::string A::tellSomething()’:
testwarns.cpp:12:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

(just for the record: personally I recommend to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic`, often one warning can save you a lot of debug time).

Comment: The warnings I like to use with clang are `-Weverything -Werror` and then a long list of `-Wno-*` arguments to disable warnings I don't care about like `-Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic`.

Answer (score 8):

The crash comes from an attempted call to an invalid `std::string` destructor:

```
std::string tellSomething() {
    std::cout << "A!" << std::endl;
}
```

The call to `a1->tellSomething();` tells the runtime to expect an automatic-storage `std::string` in the scope, which it then attempts to destroy. But that's invalid.

Technically, this is **undefined behavior**, because you're not returning what you promised you would.

Comment: its been a while since i was c++:ing, but how can this code even compile? I would expect it to fail at compile time..

Comment: Ok, sheers. Its been even much longer since I was into gcc. +1 btw, good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the vector does not delete the vector elements. You're experiencing a completely different problem caused by tellSomething() failing to return a value when it's specified to return a string.

http://ideone.com/Jo9zi

Answer (score 3):

It crashes because in linked code in method `A::tellSomething` you should return `std::string` which you are not doing. It has nothing to do with deleting `v`

Answer (score 2):

Your `tellSomething` method is missing a return value.

Adding a `return "";` to that method makes your code run just fine, albeit with memory leaks.